# open pdf from stream using pdfclown in c#

Tags: byte, filestream, pdfclown

I am really liking pdfclown in c# but I would like to open a pdf from a byte[] array or filestream. I have not found any examples of this for pdfclown. Could anyone help?

An example would be something like:

using (org.pdfclown.files.File file = new org.pdfclown.bytes.IInputStream(bytes))
{

...
}

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the right way to open a file from a byte array:

```
var bytes = . . .;
using (var file = new org.pdfclown.files.File(new org.pdfclown.bytes.Buffer(bytes)))
{
}
```

If you [check out PDF Clown from its repository](http://sourceforge.net/p/clown/code/) (version 0.1.2.1 or later) or download the next release, you can even use this ultra-simple constructor:

```
byte[] bytes = . . .;
using (var file = new org.pdfclown.files.File(bytes))
{
}
```

or, in case of System.IO.Stream:

```
System.IO.Stream stream = . . .;
using (var file = new org.pdfclown.files.File(stream))
{
}
```

If you have a plain file system path, this is your constructor:

```
string filename = . . .;
using (var file = new org.pdfclown.files.File(filename))
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to this question using the pdfclown forum. I've adapted it for my need. [enter link description here](http://sourceforge.net/p/clown/discussion/607163/thread/b64e2ea5/?limit=25#c105)

```
byte[] bytes = io.File.ReadAllBytes(@filename);

using (var ms = new io.MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    using (org.pdfclown.bytes.IInputStream i = new org.pdfclown.bytes.Stream(ms))
    {
        using (org.pdfclown.files.File file = new org.pdfclown.files.File(i))
        {

        }
    }
}
```